What is the name of the largest subobject where a map is equivariant?
Suppose we have two objects $X,Y$ with a $G$-operation and a non-equivariant map between them. In this situation, we can look at the largest subobject $X'$ of $X$ on which $f$ is $G$-equivariant.
Is there already a name for such an $X'$?

What is an "object"? Do you just mean a set? Or do you have additional structure on it?

@YCor I was mostly thinking of sets, vector spaces and rings.

I do not have an answer, but I have a suggestion. There's a tautological "name": this subobject is the equalizer of all maps in the $G$-orbit of $f$ (if you act on maps via postcomposition). If you think about this from the perspective of an arrow $f$, this is what you get when you take invariants of domain operation (the one mapping a morphism to its source). So I use $\operatorname{dom}^G(f)$ for this.
